# Can iOS apps request updated permission to selected photos?

Tags: photos, privacy

Recently while using the iOS Twitter app (8.36.3), I chose to grant access only to selected photos. I selected one photo that I wanted to share. Later I wanted to share another photo. I was taken to a UI for selecting photos which showed just one photo—the one I had selected before. There was no way to change the selected photos. Only by navigating into the iOS Settings > Privacy > Photos > Twitter do I get an option for "Edit Selected Photos". That is a very burdensome way to grant an app access to additional photos.

Is this situation a limitation of the new iOS photos privacy SDK, or is Twitter not written to correctly re-request access to selected photos? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a limitation of the Twitter app, not the SDK:

> **3) Showing the selection UI again**
>
> the recommended way is to manually request to show the selection UI again. Apple explains that if you have an app that requires full access to the photo library (e.g. some app whose main purpose is to let you browse and organize the photo library), you should add some kind of button in your UI that triggers the selection screen again.

https://mackuba.eu/2020/07/07/photo-library-changes-ios-14/

---

As further evidence that this is a limitation of the app, Facebook provides a dialog that allows me to select additional photos:

[image: Facebook add photos modal iOS 14]